# How to configure a resources in a pool to handle several agents

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to simulate a call center with chatting and in this scenario, a customer service representative can serve multiple customer chats at the same time, depending on their capabilities

I started nby creating an Employee agent and build on this, but I could not simulate a scenario in which one “Employee agent” can serve several client “chat” agents at the same time based on their total capacity, as in a real chat call center ...

Please advise how I can configure the logic so that several agents can capture / delay one resource. Or create a block in which the employee agent will bypass each chat and check if he can release it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, welcome to SOF. You luckily got a very good answer, but you typically should not ask "I need your advice" type questions, they are too open-ended. StackOverflow is designed for very specific, focused questions, it is not a discussion forum. See some more tips at https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a more advanced question and not that easy to answer in detail without building a lot of logic and functionality.

Overall I can suggest the following design, but depending on your level of expertise in AnyLogic (And Java) this might not be the best design and I am curious to see if anyone will venture any other options. But as for a moderate user (and use case), this design will be sufficient

Since there is no way to do what you asked with a standard resource pool I would suggest to setup a resource pool inside a new agent type and then either as a population or graphically (as per my design) you can send chats to these agents. Since each agent has a resource pools inside of them you can define the number of chats an agent can handle in the parameters of the agent which defines the resources in the resource pool

[image]

You can then have a function that takes a chat from the queue and gives it to the first available agent that has capacity.

[image]

And you call this function whenever something arrives in the queue as well as when something leaves a chat agent and also when a agent gets a new chat as multiple chats might arrive at the same time and we only send the first one.

Comment: You understood correctly that I am bad at AnyLogic, I recently started and I still have little experience and understanding. 
Can you please tell me how you connected these lines (in, out), and they are not red for you? What is the block icon in the ChatAgent? How did you connect the persona model to the sink?

Comment: In the Chat Agent I created I added ports and these show up as icons, with a little block around them since they will be used as an icon. You can read more here: https://anylogic.help/anylogic/interaction/ports.html (These are the same green ports you see on the standard AnyLogic objects)
If you draw from these to other ports the lines will be valid connections. 
Since you are new to AnyLogic I can suggest going through the tutorials first https://anylogic.help/tutorials/index.html 
I hope my answer helped if it did remember to accept it

Comment: Forgive me, I can't understand the logic here, two workers with different skills are described, but if I need a lot of such workers, then I need to create a population?

Comment: If you create a custom agent as I did you can either drag multiple such workers, like I dragged two of them to the canvas, or you can create a population of them if they are too many to drag to the canvas, but this will take some advanced coding to access them.

Comment: Thanks, now I'm getting an error:
The take (ChatAgent) method of type Enter <ChatAgent> is not applicable for arguments (Agent)
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your enterblock is expecting a `ChatAgent` and you are sending it an `Agent`. In the enter block be sure to have the "AgentType" option the same as the agent that will be in the queue. You are sending the Chats to the Chat Agent